# How to create a gatsby schema in combination with gatsby fragments

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am trying to define the correct schema for a gatsby graphql query so that it can return null (to make the content optional). From what I understand I need to predefine the schema in the gatsby-node.js file so that gatsby doesn't have to infer the type through the data. However I am not sure what the schema definition needs to be since we are using a gatsby fragment for querying the data. This is (part of) the query:

```
... on ContentfulWorkPage {
  comingSoon {
   id
   title
   image {
     fluid(quality: 92, maxWidth: 1280) {
       ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp_noBase64
     }
   }
   comingSoonText
  }
}
```

The problem is that I am not sure how to define the `GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp_noBase64`

what I am trying:

```
const types = `
    type ContentfulWorkPage implements Node {
      comingSoon: ComingSoon
    }

    type ComingSoon {
      id: String
      title: String
      comingSoonText: String
      image: Image
    }

    type Image {
      fluid: Fluid
    }

   type Fluid {
    quality: Int
    maxWidth: Int
    title: String
   }
  `
  createTypes(types)
```

even though I think I am on the right track I am still getting the following errors:

```
There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Unknown argument "quality" on field "fluid" of type "Image".

GraphQL request:70:21
69 |             image {
70 |               fluid(quality: 92, maxWidth: 1280) {
   |                     ^
71 |                 ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp_noBase64

File: src/templates/mainPages/work.js:105:21


 ERROR #85901  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Unknown argument "maxWidth" on field "fluid" of type "Image".

GraphQL request:70:34
69 |             image {
70 |               fluid(quality: 92, maxWidth: 1280) {
   |                                  ^
71 |                 ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp_noBase64

File: src/templates/mainPages/work.js:105:34


 ERROR #85901  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Fragment "GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp_noBase64" cannot be spread here as objects of type "Fluid" can never be of type "ContentfulFluid".

GraphQL request:71:17
70 |               fluid(quality: 92, maxWidth: 1280) {
71 |                 ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp_noBase64
   |                 ^
72 |               }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I managed to solve this after digging around in the gatsby documentation (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/actions/#printTypeDefinitions). I found that inside the `gatsby-node.js` file you can use a `printTypeDefinitions` function to print your data types, which you can then use to pre define the optional properties:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization= ({ actions }) => {
  actions.printTypeDefinitions({path: './typeDefs.txt'})
}
```

This will create a `typeDefs.txt` file in your root folder where all infered types are described. So if you are looking for more complicated type defs like I was so that they can be made optional in contentful you can:

- add some data to your optional field in contentful (or whatever backend/server you are using)
- use the function to get the type definitions out of the data
- copy whatever part you need out of the typeDefs file and
- use it in a createTypes function in the `createSchemaCustomization`

example (`comingSoon` definition was copied from the typeDevs file):

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const contentfulSomePage = `
      type ContentfulSomePage implements Node {
        comingSoon: [ContentfulCaseComingSoon] @link(by: "id", from: "comingSoon___NODE")
      }

      type ContentfulCaseComingSoon implements Node @derivedTypes @dontInfer {
        title: String
        comingSoonText: String
        image: ContentfulAsset @link(by: "id", from: "image___NODE")
      }
  `
  actions.createTypes(contentfulWorkPage)
}
```

Extra tip: if you need to just specify one property to be optional but the rest can be infered. Remove the `@dontInfer` annotation and just copy the nullable property instead of copying the whole type from the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, the printTypeDefinition was really a life saver!

Comment: Hi @Mischa, would maybe have a look at my issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68475735/gatsby-gatsby-source-strapi-there-are-conflicting-field-types-in-your-data-i

i sort of have the same problem.

Comment: Hello @Marko, 

unfortunately i only worked with gatsby for a month or so and its been a while back. I had a look at your problem but am not sure I can be of much help.

Comment: Since my issue was trying to write these (complex) types purely based on a data structure in graphql. I managed to find a way for gatsby to print the structure for me. Since you mentioned your data is gone I am not sure you can go the same route. (I hope i am not misunderstanding the issue but:) Is there any way to revert your code/data and then use the `printTypeDefinitions` to get a screenshot of your data structure as it was before, so that you can use that?